# How can I create virtual machines as part of a build process using MSBuild and MS Virtual Server and/or Hyper-V Server Virtualization?

Tags: msbuild, virtualization, hyper-v

What I would like to do is create a clean virtual machine image as the output of a build of an application.

So a new virtual machine would be created (from a template is fine, with the OS installed, and some base software installed) --- a new web site would be created in IIS, and the web app build output copied to a location on the virtual machine hard disk, and IIS configured correctly, the VM would start up and run.

I know there are MSBuild tasks to script all the administrative actions in IIS, but how do you script all the actions with Virtual machines?  Specifically, creating a new virtual machine from a template, naming it uniquely, starting it, configuring it, etc...

Specifically I was wondering if anyone has successfully implemented any VM scripting as part of a build process.

Update: I assume with Hyper-V, there is a different set of libraries/APIs to script virtual machines, anyone played around with this?  And anyone with real practical experience of doing something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [Powershell Management library for Hyper-V on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/PSHyperv). Some features:

> Finding a VM
>   Connecting to a VM
>   Discovering and manipulating Machine states
>   Backing up, exporting and snapshotting VMs
>   Adding and removing VMs, configuring motherboard settings.
>   Manipulating Disk controllers, drives and disk images
>   Manipluating Network Interface Cards
>   Working with VHD files

Answer (score 3):

You can actually script a fair number of tasks in MS Virtual Server:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/vs/default.mspx?mfr=true

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368876(VS.85).aspx

Also Virtual PC guy has got a ton of stuff on his blog about scripting Virtual Server/PC and now Hyper-V here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/default.aspx

VMware has similar capabilities:

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/scripting-API/